# How to produce time series for each row of a data frame with an unnamed first column

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, subset

So this is I'm sure a fairly elementary problem. I have a data frame that has data for 10 years for a bunch of countries. It looks like this. The data frame is df.

```
                    X2003 X2004 X2005 X2006 X2007 X2008 X2009 X2010 X2011 X2012
Afghanistan         7.321 7.136 6.930 6.702 6.456 6.196 5.928 5.659 5.395 5.141
Albania             2.097 2.004 1.919 1.849 1.796 1.761 1.744 1.741 1.748 1.760
Algeria             2.412 2.448 2.507 2.580 2.656 2.725 2.781 2.817 2.829 2.820
Angola              6.743 6.704 6.657 6.598 6.523 6.434 6.331 6.218 6.099 5.979
Antigua and Barbuda 2.268 2.246 2.224 2.203 2.183 2.164 2.146 2.130 2.115 2.102
Argentina           2.340 2.310 2.286 2.268 2.254 2.241 2.228 2.215 2.201 2.188
```

The first column is metadata. It hasn't got a name. I'd like to use qplot to plot time series for each of the rows. Something like the following command:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot (data = df, binwidth = 1, geom="freqpoly") but I get the following error

Error: stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x.
```

I would like to set x = first column but I don't have a name on that column. Do I have to create a first column of country names? If so, how do I do that? 
Seems like there should be an easier way. Sorry if this is so elementary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you need, maybe something like this?

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df$metadata <- row.names(df)
df <- melt(df, "metadata")
ggplot(df, aes(variable, value, group = metadata, color = metadata)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry that's not quite what I was looking for. I guess it's not a frequency polygon but a time series. I want to plot annual series for each country over time. So for Afghanistan I would want see the value at 2000, then the value at 2001 etc...

Comment: @CharlesFogel, see my update using your data. There is nothing special here really, just use `melt` once

Answer (score 0):

following your comments, I guess you want this kind of graphic?

```
# Create a "long" data frame rather than a "wide" data frame.

country <- rep(c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria","Angola",
             "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina"),each = 10, times = 1)
year <- rep(c(2003:2012), each = 1, times = 6)
value <- runif(60, 0, 50)

foo <- data.frame(country,year,value,stringsAsFactors=F)
foo$year <- as.factor(foo$year)

# Draw a ggplot figure

ggplot(foo, aes(x=year, y = value,group = country, color = country)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

Comment: Yep. That gives a time series for each country. But wow, that seems complicated though. I already have the data in each row for each country. Isn't there a way to make the plot with each column as a tick on the x-axis?

Comment: What do you mean by saying tick? Could you run the following and see if this is what you mean? `ggplot(foo, aes(x=year, y = value,group = country, color = country, shape = country)) + geom_point()`

Comment: No. Your first solution was correct. It just requires a lot of data manipulation that I don't understand.

Comment: If your data is the one you initially showed, David showed you how to convert a "wide" data frame to a "long" data frame. You want to use `melt()` in the `reshape2` package. That will do the work for you. If your data is in another format, you perhaps want to ask another question related to that.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look up melt.

Comment: `melt()` will create a data frame like foo in my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hi. Here is a very similar solution to what Charles correctly suggested using melt. I've used the package ggvis to produce the plot and made sure the scale of the y-axsis is fixed at 0. The block of code below assumes that df is already read into R.

**R Code:**

```
    library(reshape2)
    library(ggvis)

    str(df) # just to demonstrate initial structure of df....results in coment block below

    # data.frame': 6 obs. of  11 variables:
    #  $ Country: chr  "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "Angola" ...
    #  $ X2003  : num  7.32 2.1 2.41 6.74 2.27 ...
    #  $ X2004  : num  7.14 2 2.45 6.7 2.25 ...
    #  $ X2005  : num  6.93 1.92 2.51 6.66 2.22 ...
    #  $ X2006  : num  6.7 1.85 2.58 6.6 2.2 ...
    #  $ X2007  : num  6.46 1.8 2.66 6.52 2.18 ...
    #  $ X2008  : num  6.2 1.76 2.73 6.43 2.16 ...
    #  $ X2009  : num  5.93 1.74 2.78 6.33 2.15 ...
    #  $ X2010  : num  5.66 1.74 2.82 6.22 2.13 ...
    #  $ X2011  : num  5.39 1.75 2.83 6.1 2.12 ...
    #  $ X2012  : num  5.14 1.76 2.82 5.98 2.1 ...

    df1 <- melt(df, "Country")

    df1 %>% ggvis(~factor(variable),~value,stroke=~Country) %>% layer_lines(strokeWidth:=2.5) %>% 
    add_axis("x",title="Year") %>% scale_numeric("y",zero=TRUE)
```

I never really started using ggplot, but when I saw ggvis and especially its use of %>% pipe operator introduced in the magrittr package I was hooked. Best....

Comment: Thank you for that interesting approach.